# X11 opengl on Snow Leopard

Tags: opengl, osx-snow-leopard, x11

I inherited an old code base using OpenGL inside X11. 
The header includes is like this

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <X11/Intrinsic.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <X11/cursorfont.h>
```

I want to port this to Snow Leopard, my basic problem so far is that I can't get the proper headers or maybe I should say I cant get xcode to  bind against the correct headers. 
I need to use things like

```
GLXDrawable drawable; 
XVisualInfo *ptr;
GLXContext MainContext;
XSetWindowAttributes wa;
```

I tried to install X11 dev (I tried http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki , I tried using fink to install x11 opengl dev libs and ...). Obviously I am not a C programmer (I have rather good experience in Objective c and iOS development though).
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X11 server for MacOS X is rather limited and in my experience it has rather poor OpenGL support. So instead of trying to fit a square pig into a round hole I'd just use MacOS X native OpenGL API. The probably most easy way to get your thing portable is replace all that windowing specific stuff with GLFW, a neat OpenGL specific wrapper around X11/GLX, Win32 and MacOS X, that cares about OpenGL context creation and user input. BTW, user input: You'll have to adjust that one, too.

Don't get me wrong, I really like X11/GLX. And if I had not made those bad experiences with MacOS X's (Leopard) X11 server support for OpenGL, I'd gladly give advice how to tackle it. But I think in the end you'll keep your sanity if you just replace that X11 code with GLFW.

Comment: Thanks, If I am going to rewrite a lot of code (given that this code is not meant to be portable and is to run on like less than 10 macs only), why you recommend GLFW, instead of using Native solutions? Another issue that I didn't bring up yet is OpenMotif, I have a rather complicated UI built using OpenMotif that I don't know what to do with I'd better not change it if possible and just port it for the time being.

Comment: You could use the native API as well of course. NSOpenGLView is actually rather simple to use. OpenMotif, well, Motif doesn't really cater to the expectations on modern UIs. Also Mac users expect their applications to adhere to the Cocoa look and feel. And let's face it, X11 is not native to MacOS X.